# SHAP on LSTM (multivariate with different input sizes time series data) - 'NoneType' object is not callable error

Tags: python, lstm, shap

I am using SHAP to understand the LSTM model predictions. My data is x, y coordinates (with padding) - I used the code given here (Sequence LSTM
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/how-to-feed-lstm-with-different-input-array-sizes/48814#48814)

After the LSTM is trained I used SHAP - explainer but getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (but its not clear what is None). How to solve this error?

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Masking
import numpy as np

 

# Parameters
N = 1000
halfN = int(N/2)
dimension = 2
lstm_units = 3

# Data
np.random.seed(123)  # to generate the same numbers
# create sequence lengths between 1 to 10
seq_lens = np.random.randint(1, 10, halfN)
X_zero = np.array([np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(seq_len, dimension)) for seq_len in seq_lens])
y_zero = np.zeros((halfN, 1))
X_one = np.array([np.random.normal(1, 1, size=(seq_len, dimension)) for seq_len in seq_lens])
y_one = np.ones((halfN, 1))
p = np.random.permutation(N)  # to shuffle zero and one classes
X = np.concatenate((X_zero, X_one))[p]
y = np.concatenate((y_zero, y_one))[p]


# Padding and Masking
special_value = -10.0
max_seq_len = max(seq_lens)
Xpad = np.full((N, max_seq_len, dimension), fill_value=special_value)
for s, x in enumerate(X):
    seq_len = x.shape[0]
    Xpad[s, 0:seq_len, :] = x
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Masking(mask_value=special_value, input_shape=(max_seq_len, dimension)))
model2.add(LSTM(lstm_units))
model2.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model2.summary())
model2.fit(Xpad, y, epochs=50, batch_size=32)


import shap

# define the explainer
explainer = shap.Explainer(model2)

# explain the predictions of the pipeline on the first two samples
shap_values = explainer(Xpad[:2])


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-dd276207f9fd> in <module>
      1 # explain the predictions of the pipeline on the first two samples
----> 2 shap_values = explainer(Xtrain[:2], max_evals=4000)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/explainers/_permutation.py in __call__(self, max_evals, main_effects, error_bounds, batch_size, outputs, silent, *args)
     72         """ Explain the output of the model on the given arguments.
     73         """
---> 74         return super().__call__(
     75             *args, max_evals=max_evals, main_effects=main_effects, error_bounds=error_bounds, batch_size=batch_size,
     76             outputs=outputs, silent=silent

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/explainers/_explainer.py in __call__(self, max_evals, main_effects, error_bounds, batch_size, outputs, silent, *args, **kwargs)
    256             feature_names = [[] for _ in range(len(args))]
    257         for row_args in show_progress(zip(*args), num_rows, self.__class__.__name__+" explainer", silent):
--> 258             row_result = self.explain_row(
    259                 *row_args, max_evals=max_evals, main_effects=main_effects, error_bounds=error_bounds,
    260                 batch_size=batch_size, outputs=outputs, silent=silent, **kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/explainers/_permutation.py in explain_row(self, max_evals, main_effects, error_bounds, batch_size, outputs, silent, *row_args)
    130 
    131                 # evaluate the masked model
--> 132                 outputs = fm(masks, zero_index=0, batch_size=batch_size)
    133 
    134                 if row_values is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/utils/_masked_model.py in __call__(self, masks, zero_index, batch_size)
     62                 full_masks = np.zeros((int(np.sum(masks >= 0)), self._masker_cols), dtype=np.bool)
     63                 _convert_delta_mask_to_full(masks, full_masks)
---> 64                 return self._full_masking_call(full_masks, zero_index=zero_index, batch_size=batch_size)
     65 
     66         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shap/utils/_masked_model.py in _full_masking_call(self, masks, zero_index, batch_size)
     91                     masked_inputs = self.masker(delta_ind, *self.args).copy()
     92                 else:
---> 93                     masked_inputs = self.masker(mask, *self.args)
     94 
     95                 # wrap the masked inputs if they are not already in a tuple

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```